# NSDateFormatter dateFromString crash (in call from formatter.date(from: String)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I'm getting a crash reported on my call to date(from:) on my formatter:

```
guard let date = DateFormatter.longYearFormatter(timeZone: timeZone).date(from: dateString) else { return }
```

`dateString` here is non-optional, and looks like: "2021-11-05T14:03:00GMT-04:00"

This is the `longYearFormatter`:

```
static func longYearFormatter(timeZone: TimeZone? = .current) -> DateFormatter {
        return DateFormatter(timeZone: timeZone,
                             format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ")
    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000000000007b
0
libicucore.A.dylib
icu::Calendar::clear() + 120
1
CoreFoundation
__cficu_ucal_clear + 24
2
CoreFoundation
__cficu_ucal_clear + 24
3
CoreFoundation
CFDateFormatterGetAbsoluteTimeFromString + 392
4
CoreFoundation
CFDateFormatterCreateDateFromString + 104
5
Foundation
getObjectValue + 268
6
Foundation
-[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:] + 196
7
Foundation
-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:] + 60
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? It doesn't happen every time this function is called and seems to be relatively rare.

I've tried running my simulator in different languages, regions, time zones, 24 vs 12hr time, etc, and I can't repro it myself.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE**

Here is what the custom DateFormatter init looks like:

```
public extension DateFormatter {
    private convenience init(timeZone: TimeZone?,
                             format: String) {
        self.init()
        self.timeZone = timeZone ?? .current
        locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormat = format
    }
```

Comment: Where is that init from, `init(timeZone: timeZone, format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ")`?

Comment: What is the value of `timeZone`? The problem seems to be with `Calendar` inside Core Foundation.  Have you tested with devices that aren't using the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: Is the given date an example of when it crashes?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry about that, I added in what that init looks like also! I'm also not entirely sure which date it's crashing on, since the report is just from Crashlytics, but it should look very close to that one

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried with a few different values for timeZone (EST / MST), but I haven't tried with a non-Gregorian calendar! Is that do-able with a simulator?

*EDIT* - Actually, I've already switched to Chinese region / language and tried it with no crash unfortunately

Comment: You can set the calendar for the formatter to test different kinds. You didn't answer about the date sample.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson edited my answer there - "I'm also not entirely sure which date it's crashing on, since the report is just from Crashlytics, but it should look very close to that one"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson @Paulw11 I added in `calendar = Calendar(identifier: .chinese)` into the init above, and it does cause the first guard let to fail, but still doesn't crash on date(from:)

Comment: Does this happens with date:time during summer/winter daylight savings time change ?